# Unpacking an MST file without an MSI file

Tags: unpacking

I've looked this up for a few days now, but I can only find software like MSTView or Orca, which both require an MSI file to unpack the MST.

Is there a way to unpack an MST file without an MSI file?

Answer (score 4):

7 zip understand both msi and mst files and can extract them to their constituent files /folders

**C:>ndff -d f: *.mst | grep SP1**

`\Virtual PC 2004 SP1\Virtual PC 2004 SP1\1031.mst`

**C:>file "f:\Virtual PC 2004 SP1\Virtual PC 2004 SP1\1031.mst"**

`f:\Virtual PC 2004 SP1\Virtual PC 2004 SP1\1031.mst; 
CDF V2 Document, Little Endian, 
Os: Windows, Version 5.1, Code page: 1252, Title: Installation Database, 
Subject: Microsoft Virtual PC 2004 Installer, Author: Microsoft Corporation, 
Keywords: Installer, Comments: WiX-basierter Installer fⁿr VPC2004, 
Create Time/Date: Thu Jul 29 06:49:22 2004, 
Name of Creating Application: Windows Installer, 
Security: 1, Template: ;1033, Last Saved By: ;1031, 
Revision Number: 
{CCCAFDDE-ECEC-4AE4-BD97-047076BBD4A9}5.3.582.16;
{CCCAFDDE-ECEC-4AE4-BD97-047076BBD4A9}5.3.582.16;
{339DD19A-341A-4CED-BC00-5B40BDED4DA2}, 
Number of Pages: 200, 
Number of Characters: 0`

**C:>"c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" l "f:\Virtual PC 2004 SP1\Virtual PC 2004 SP1\1031.mst"**

`
    7-Zip 9.20  Copyright (c) 1999-2010 Igor Pavlov  2010-11-18

```
Listing archive: f:\Virtual PC 2004 SP1\Virtual PC 2004 SP1\1031.mst

--
Path = f:\Virtual PC 2004 SP1\Virtual PC 2004 SP1\1031.mst
Type = Compound
Cluster Size = 512
Sector Size = 64

Date      Time    Attr         Size   Compressed  Name
------------------- ----- ------------ ------------  ------------------------
                .....           42           64  !Property
                .....          132          192  !Error
                .....          144          192  !Dialog
                .....           36           64  !Registry
                .....          982         1024  !Control
                .....           14           64  !TextStyle
                .....           48           64  !ActionText
                .....          820          832  !_StringPool
                .....        23374        23552  !_StringData
                .....           32           64  !RadioButton
                .....          592          640  [5]SummaryInformation
------------------- ----- ------------ ------------  ------------------------
                             26216        26752  11 files, 0 folders `
```

**C:>dir "f:\Virtual PC 2004 SP1\Virtual PC 2004 SP1\1031.mst"**

```
`Directory of f:\Virtual PC 2004 SP1\Virtual PC 2004 SP1  

 30/08/2006  12:41            30,208 1031.mst  
           1 File(s)         30,208 bytes  
           0 Dir(s)   1,154,138,112 bytes free`
```